# Is this possible to check back which application paste the NSPasteboardItem on the Pasteboard?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nspasteboard

I would like to know  how can I get this information? I can keep polling, and checking which application is running, and see the pasteboard count at the same time. But I am afraid this way is not 100% accurate. For example, if the user go to app A, and copy things, in the pasteboard, the pasteboard count increase. But the second poll request did not started yet, and the user switch to to app B, then, the poll start, it may mess up the logic. So, any way suggested to find out the NSPasteboard is from which app? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not supported. One hacky way would be to have a system wide keyboard hook to detect copy (ctrl+c) operation. When user presses this key, you can check the foreground process.

Comment: But, the user can copy things from the menu, within pressing the keyboard